# How does web page writing differ from blog and article writing?

Tags: creative-writing, technical-writing, content-strategy

Yesterday I was talking with a client and he asked me to write web page content. I told him that I can write blogs and articles.

He suggesed that I should learn web page writing, but I searched on Google for one day and I'm not able to find the exact difference between them. How does web page writing differ from blog and article writing?

Comment: I read a great book that answers this exact question and many others about writing for the web. It's called *Letting Go of the Words: Writing Web Content that Works* by Janice Reddish.

Comment: Welcome to W.SE.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that what your client wants is "content management", or more specifically, "[copywriting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copywriting)".

It differs from blog writing and articles, because it's generally shorter and more to-the-point. It aims to convey a specific information about what the site has to offer. For example, a description of products, of services, or short texts that need to attract or guide the user. It supports the function of the website.

A blog and an article are generally more free-form, and with a personal touch both in the ideas and in the style. A "copy" can be stilish and fancy, of course, but the purpose is not to express the author's point of view or feelings, but rather a specific message in line with the website's offering.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed explaination. I got my answer.

Comment: Thank you! I suggest you, though, to wait for more answers to come, before to select one as "best answer" (although I do appreciate that you liked mine!). This way other members are more welcome to give maybe even better responses :)

Comment: As a copywriter I would add that much copy has a strict word or space limit. EG your picture caption can be one line, 2" wide, no cheating on the fonts, fontsize, or spacing. Similarly for Headlines or Titles, and no multi-line title fudging. Ditto for a brochure or product  product description: Here is your rectangle, fill it in, no abbreviations or acronyms and don't let words break over lines! This adds a new creative element to writing, to fit in a container (without cheating) and still leave nothing out of what should be said. This is one reason ad copy is more direct and less flowery.

Answer (score 1):

Everything FraEnrico said : It's about professional rather than personal, an informational style rather than a viewpoint. While blogs and articles can be considered web page content, they are not the only type.

It sounds like your client already has an idea of the sort of things he wants, though I understand that you might not have wanted to give him the impression you didn't know what he meant. I find the question "Can you give me an example of the sort of thing you had in mind?" particularly useful when dealing with customer expectations - we might agree on what we think he means, but with clients this might not be the same as their understanding of what they believe they have asked.

Answer (score 1):

There is another consideration: your client may be referring to inverted-pyramid writing. Front-load crucial data and answers in order to grab the reader quickly, to aide the reader in scanning for data, and to help gain and keep better SEO rankings.

Or in older-school, journalistic writing terms: avoid burying the lede.

In article or blog writing, it can be appropriate to use the more traditional introduction-exposition-conclusion format, which is aimed and suited to printed out out in which you reward the reader for their diligence reading through your piece by giving them the conclusion or climax at the end of building the case for it through your exposition.

Moreover, in website writing and modern technical writing, we tend to use active voice, short declarative sentences, and imperative voice for directions.

Me, I'd ask the client for clarification.